# How to send event on plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using the **[leanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/)** plugin and I like to add some code, in order to meet my needs.

What I did, is to use it as a modal dialog, and I have two buttons. The one button closing the modal dialog, and it is fine. The second button is responsible to use the data inserted into the dialog, and then to close the dialog.

What I am looking now, is when I click the second button, first to validate the data, and then to close the dialog, but this functionality does not exists in the plugin. So, how can I add something like the following:

```
$('selector').leanModal('close');
```

Is there a way ?

**Note :** I hope that my description is ok.

Comment: Maybe you could change the plugin?

Comment: This plugin is not very well featured. There is a `close_modal` function, but you cannot access it external to the plugin itself. I'd use a different modal plugin. There are many of them.

Comment: I have already apply modifications on the plugin, but I don't know how to add the extra functionality described above.

Comment: `I have already apply modifications on the plugin` there is a bad idea itself. If a plugin doesn't work as you need, use a different one. If you must amend a plugin, prototype it yourself so that if there is a later update, maintenance won't be a complete nightmare.

Comment: The plugin is part of my project, so, I do not plan to update it in the feature. Is good inought for what I need it.